# How do holders of a literal interpretation of Genesis 1 interpret the word "rule" in verse 16 in light of its apparent contradiction to observation?

Tags: genesis, creation

Genesis 1:16, King James Version, reads:

> And God made two great lights; the greater light to rule the day, and the lesser light to rule the night: he made the stars also.

I am specifically asking how the word "rule" is interpreted by people who take Genesis 1 literally.

The sun could be said to "rule the day," since it is only visible during daylight hours, and it is prominent in the sky.

However how can the moon be said to "rule the night" given that ancient man could see that the moon is visible in the sky both in daylight and at night practically every day of the month, and that there are approximately two days of the month when it is not visible at night? Also, they could see that the moon is not prominent in the sky every night that it is visible. Ancient man was keenly aware of the movements of the moon. They based their calendar on it.

Comment: On cloudy days the sun is not visible.  "Rule" is the realm of influence or dominion rather than the act of ruling.

Comment: @MikeBorden I like your answer, would you consider making it an answer to the question?

Comment: Thank you.  I will make an attempt when time permits.

Comment: Every culture associates the moon with night, because that is when it is generally visible, and the sun with day, because that is when it's generally visible. Literal interpretations of Genesis may be flawed on other grounds, but this can be trivially reconciled.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not the sun or moon is visible is not what determines the "rule".  Rule is defined as rule, dominion, realm, domain.  The sun rules the day in that daytime is the sun's domain.  On especially cloudy days the sun cannot be seen but it is still there "ruling" the day.

The same can be said of the moon.  It gives varying amounts of light to the earth depending upon it's phase but night is it's domain.  It may be visible during the day but what light it gives is dwarfed by the greater light whose realm the daytime is.

One of the purposes stated in Genesis for these two dominions, these two rulings, is to separate day from night and to divide the light from the darkness.  If the Sun were visible in the night then it would have dominion there as well for it is the greater light.  Darkness has no source and only exists in the absence of light.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the light-pollution, try getting far away from towns and cities on a cloudless night, and take a walk.

- If there is a full moon, you'll be able to see quite clearly.
- If there is a partial moon, you be able to see, but not as well.
- If there is no moon that night, you'll be almost helpless.

The Moon obviously controls your behaviour at night.
It *rules* over what you can reasonably do.

This is objectively true, even from the point of view of atheistic science.
It has nothing to do with Genesis or religious interpretation.